# C++ Winsock UDP sendto succeeds but I don't see the data being sent

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, windows-ce, winsock

I am working with UDP sockets over an ethernet interface between my workstation (192.168.0.1) and my WinCE6 device (192.168.0.100).

From my workstation I can send UDP packets toward my WinCE device where I have a receiving socket set up and properly receiving data on port 9002; the device then properly echoes back data to my workstation.

I want my device to answer to my workstation on a specific port: 9001.

This is the server running into my device, it is the same as [this](http://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/) but I modified the socket bind to the address of the specific interface and I changed the `PORT` define:

```
#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 9002   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

void test_udp( void )
{
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
int slen , recv_len;
char buf[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;

slen = sizeof(si_other) ;

//Initialise winsock
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    return;
}

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf( "Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( 0xC0A80064 );
server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

//Bind
if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    return;
}

//keep listening for data
while(1)
{
    //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);

    //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
    if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return;
    }

    // *** CHANGE THE SEND PORT
    si_other.sin_port = htons( 9001 );

    //now reply the client with the same data
    if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return;
    }
}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return;
}
```

**When I added the line below the `// *** CHANGE THE SEND PORT` comment to try to send the data back to port 9001, I am getting an appropriate return value for sendto which matches the number of bytes I expect to have been sent, but I don't see the data coming on my workstation (listening on 9001).**

I have been banging my head against this and I cant see anything wrong. In the modified example,  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: A firewall on my development PC was at fault. It allowed traffic back on the same port my PC was sending on, but blocked traffic on any other port. Resolving that allowed the the traffic to be sent without code changes. I had disabled the firewall previously, but did not realize that the OS had flagged the ethernet as a "public network", which still had the firewall enabled.

Comment: How do you know that your receiving program is working?  Have you tried using wireshark to see what is hitting the wire?  It would also be helpful if you printed out the return code of the `sendto()` because it is going to be tough to tell if it failed or not otherwise.

Comment: the first thing to do is check bind and use WSAGetLastError. the second thing at any pace check with printing eg: if you get a message or not. use a blocking function to receive and send. the best thing I used to do I made a chat program using udp sockets and multithreading

Comment: Why are you changing `sin_port`? It will already contain the sending port number after `recvfrom()`. That's the port you want to reply to. Remove that line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If, as you said, you are not getting a SOCKET_ERROR from the sendto and you are seeing an appropriate return value, this means that your OS was able to find a route toward the destination IP and was able to buffer your send request.

**To change the send port it's ok if you want to answer to a different port with respect to the one from which you received data** but note that this is not a typical case; the si_other struct in fact will contain the source address after the recvfrom and so the source port too. **So keep your code as it is on your device side.**

If you are not seeing data flowing to your workstation probably, in a simple networking context as your development environment, **the problem is on the workstation: it is not receiving data**.
I agree with @Daniel that you have to investigate with WireShark to see what's happening to packets.

Hope this helps

Comment: 1. If you don't get an error on send it does not mean the target host:port was found. It only means there was a route to the host and that the datagram got buffered for sending. 2. Setting `sin_port` is not good: it is a waste of time. It is already set to the correct value for a reply. 'If you would answer to that address you would answer to the source port' is exactly what you want to do. Setting `sin_port` to some fixed value either sets the wrong value or doesn't change the correct value.

Comment: Thanks EJP. But I don't understand why you are saying that changing sin_port sets the wrong value or doesn't change it. This is not a typical case to answer to a different port than the one we received from but still it is possible...

Comment: `sin_port` contains the source ported the incoming datagram. The port you should respond to. There is no point in setting it at all. Either the value you set it to is wrong, in which case the response won't arrive, or it is right, in which case setting it did nothing - it didn't change the value. This seems rather obvious. There is no evidence in the question that the peer is using two ports, and therefore no reason for your recommendation to keep the code.

Comment: Ok, I see. You are saying that it is possible to change the destination port but you don't think this is the case. However what I read is that Briggs was able to send from his development machine to port 9002 on the mobile device and see data echoed back on the dev machine on port 9002. After that he changes his code on the dev machine to listen on 9001. It seems like he wants to receive from the dev machine (communication coming from any port) and answer back to 9001. That's why I suggested to keep the code.

Comment: However probably the "mistake" is that Briggs has never received on port 9002 on the dev machine but he always received data on the dev machine on the source port used to start the communciation (as expected in a typical case). So @Briggs to me you have to clear up what's your target client server architecture...

Comment: I'm not interested in the 'so you are saying' game. I *have already said* that it is not shown by anything in the question that the destination port for the reply is different from the source port of the request, and that your recommendation to leave this peculiar feature of the OP's code is therefore completely unmotivated.

Comment: @EJP, It is my intent to respond on a port that is different than the port I received on. The server is broadcasting on port 9002, but is listening for responses or queries on port 9001. However, I have determined that the code above was correct. The reason I did not see the traffic was due to a firewall in place on my development PC which allowed inbound data on the port I initiated, but blocked data on other ports. The OS flagged the ethernet connection as "public" and enabled the firewall. Clearing that away allowed me to see the expected results without code changes.